# Rails on Github Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-pages

I recently set up my own Github Pages site, and I want to extend the functionality. I have a very basic site set up, with some HTML, CSS, Tailwind, and jQuery. I want to use Rails on my site for a blog. I was planning on using Jekyll, but I had some weird installation errors that put me off, and I want to learn Rails and Ruby anyhow, so I can broaden my horizons. Is it possible to host a site with Rails on Github Pages?

Note: I saw the older thread from ~2015 regarding a similar question, but I wasn't sure if those answers are up to date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub Pages only for static sites. Here is the quote from [the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service that takes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files straight from a repository on GitHub,

If you want to host Rails-app try [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/free) or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I saw Heroku but I don't want to leave the comfort of a domain Github offers, I don't have cash to spend on a domain. I've heard of things like Middleman and Nanoc, can I use them with Rails and have them work on Github Pages?

Comment: As I understand these tools create a static build. This build you can push into a repository and host it on GitHub Pages.

Comment: @SameerIyengar Last time I checked you could obtain a custom domain on Heroku, too (for free). Something like `yourappname.herokuapp.com` I think. Did you look into that? I think it's a lot easier than using a tool just to try and host a dynamic website on a service that explicitly says it only hosts static content :)

Comment: But you won't get SSL if you use custom domain on Heroku for free. Meaning you can use `https://yourappname.herokuapp.com`, but for custom domain `http://example.com`, in free tier you can't have `https://example.com`

Comment: @Viktor Thanks! I'll look into that, still wondering if it's worth shifting completely from Github Pages to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks @cdadityang for the additional info!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible since GitHub Pages only provide serverless static site hosting, there is no server to run Rails app.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've heard of things like Middleman and Nanoc, can I use them with Rails and have them work on Github Pages?